# Kubernetes(GKE) cronjob not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: node-timer-analytics-parser-cronjob
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: node-timer-analytics-parser-cronjob
            image: round0.azurecr.io/node-timer-analytics-parser:latest
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; npm start
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: regsecret
```

I have a following YAML file which creates a cronjob but **$ kubectl get cronjob** cmd gives this 
$ kubectl get cronjob

```
NAME                                     KIND
node-timer-analytics-parser-controller   CronJob.v1beta1.batch
```

also **$ kubectl get job** says ***NO resources found.***

I also tried this **$ kubectl describe cronjob node-timer-analytics-parser-controller** which gives

```
Name:       node-timer-analytics-parser-controller
Namespace:  default
Labels:     <none>
Events:     <none>
```

This docker image/container does some extensive sql queries(40-50 queries in parallel) to sql database.
I tested the docker container locally it runs without any issues. One complete execution probably takes around 1- 5 minutes. I don't understand why it is not working in **Kubernetes**

I even tried the [example of the k8 documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job) it seems to be working done know what is the issue with my cronjob.

Comment: Have you looked at logs for the cronjob? Does it ever start?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are running Kubernetes 1.8, according to the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes) 1.7.8 is the default version run in GKE. You can check which version you are running by using `kubectl version`

If you are running < 1.8 then you will need to enable cron jobs as per [the CronJob documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#prerequisites). I don't use GKE, but looks like you do this at cluster create time:

```
gcloud alpha container clusters create my-cluster --enable-kubernetes-alpha
```

For more info, take a look at [About Alpha Features](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/alpha-clusters#about_feature_stages)

Even with 1.8 is seems to be listed on the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes) as a new feature

> You can now run CronJobs on your Container Engine cluster. CronJob is a Beta feature in Kubernetes version 1.8.

So you might need to run an upgrade.

I also notice that you are using an azure container. Might be worth starting with the example `CronJob` to see if you can get that to work first.

Comment: I do have the 1.8 k8 version in GKE. I even tried this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job and this worked fine.